# Como automatizar el login en una web

Tags: vba

tengo un problemita que aun no le he encontrado la solucion, recientemente me registré en una web y me dispuse a crear un login automatico con macros de excel. Todo parece funcionar, pero no logro rellenar los campos solicitados y por ende no se logea.

este es el código que he usado:

```
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer

 Sub auto_open()

 Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
 Dim MyURL As String
 On Error GoTo Err_Clear
 MyURL = "https://www.presearch.org/login"
 Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
 MyBrowser.Silent = True
 MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
 MyBrowser.Visible = True
 Do
 Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
 HTMLDoc.all.Email.Value = "mi email" 'Aqui pongo mi email de login
 HTMLDoc.all.passwd.Value = "mi contraseña" 'Aqui pongo mi contraseña
 For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("input")
 If MyHTML_Element.Type = "submit" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
 Next
Err_Clear:
 If Err <> 0 Then
 Err.Clear
 Resume Next
 End If
 End Sub
```

Gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usar un css [selector de atributo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub detalles()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True

        .Navigate2 "https://www.presearch.org/login"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .querySelector("[type=email]").Value = "BobConstruye@hotmail.com"
            .querySelector("[type=password]").Value = "contrasena"
            .querySelector(".form-group [type=submit]").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        '****************
        Stop
        '****************
    End With
End Sub
```